# Can I put a variable in Wordpress post title?

Tags: wordpress

I have a topic which is applicable for different ethnicities: Asian, hispanic, African ... I just wanted to know can I write a topic where the focus-keyword changes with search?

E.g. If someone searches, how to change DNA for (variable) people

If in the list, Wordpress could fill in the blank with that variable.

(Something that Spun text programs use)

I just want to use the same article for everyone, but don't know how to do it.

Thanks for reading. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ghitomi, this site expects that you show your research efforts and attempts to solve the problem on your own. We don't provide code from scratch, we help to fix existent code. See [About] and [ask]. Oh, and welcome :)

Comment: what did you do before saying "I dont know" ?

Comment: @wordpresser Thanks for your reply. I expected a pointer of some sort. I fail Googling for want of proper search keywords. Even this time I tried to search (even here too) but results showed I should type something else. Elsewhere someone put this"Look into creating tags in the admin for the appropriate posts and the search functrion will find them - or create a post handler for selected tags". I can't decipher what that meant. Even some link to some site or course is welcome. I need to step on this myself.